# Reals in Range; unexpected result for non-standard Precision

Tags: iterators, arbitrary-precision

I think I have encountered advice against using inexact numbers in specifications of ranges and iterator many times. I don't think I ever saw an example of unexpected results though, but today I found the following example.

```
dd = 0.3233150`200.;
kk = 40;
delX = 1/10;
testOutcome = Range[dd, dd - kk*delX, -delX];
Length@testOutcome == kk + 1
```

> ```
> False
> ```

`Table` appears to work in the same way.

```
Length@Table[ii, {ii, dd, dd - kk*delX, -delX}] ==  kk + 1
```

> ```
> False
> ```

This is a somewhat unexpected to me. For example, if we set `dd` to `0`, or if we do `dd = N@dd`, we get `True`. Obviously the workaround is to not use real numbers in `Range` and friends. Note that the documentation of `Range` has the following example

```
Range[0, 10, N[Pi, 24]]
```

So that this is indeed documented behavior.

**Question**: Does anybody know why `Range` behaves this way? Can problems also occur when using `MachinePrecision`?

Comment: ``delX = 0.1`200;`` magically fixes everything.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Great observation.

Comment: Interesting example of calculations with arbitrary precision numbers and exact numbers. Observe that `z1 = dd; Do[z1 = z1 - 1/10, {40}]; z2 = dd - 4/10; z1 < z2` gives `True` (ask for `z2-z1`), so `z1` is rejected as an element of the range.

Comment: @FredSimons you have a typo. You need to be subtracting `40/10`, not `4/10` and then the inequality gives `False`. But `z2-z1` does indeed gve something enlightening.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Yes, you are right; somewhere this typo must have entered my computation. When you do it with 40/10, indeed z1==z2 gives True, but  the first decimals of z1 are -3.6766850000000000000000 and of z2 are -3.6766849999999999999999. So with respect to the decimals, z1 is less than z2; probably the reason for rejection. (That was my original computation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not encountered that problem before that I know of.  It doesn't seem *too* surprising to me however considering this:

- [Instability in DeleteDuplicates and Tally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6166895/618728)

As an alternative consider [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) (new in 10.1):

```
sd = Subdivide[dd, dd - kk*delX, kk];

Length[sd]

sd == Append[testOutcome, dd - kk*delX]
```

> ```
> 41
>
> True
> ```

---

[LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp) made an astute observation:  "`` delX = 0.1`200; `` magically fixes everything."

Relating to the Q&A linked above these would *appear* to be identical:

```
SameQ[dd - kk*delX, dd - kk*0.1`200]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

But they are not:

```
Order[dd - kk*delX, dd - kk*0.1`200]
```

> ```
> -1   (* would be 0 if identical *)
> ```

[`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) shows the difference:

```
{dd - kk*delX, dd - kk*0.1`200} // InputForm
```

> ```
> {-3.67668499999 . . . 9999999`201.0558305693779,
>  -3.67668500000 . . . 000001`199.92963954357063}
> ```

Comment: Huh. +1 for the last two code blocks. I was expecting, that there'd be a trailing `999999...` or `000...0001`, but didn't figure that `InputForm` is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `Subdivide` sounds great :). I like your analysis, but I think the fact that `Order` gives `-1` is not what decides this. I believe this because `Order[dd + kk*N[delX, 200],
 dd + kk*delX]` gives `-1`, but `Length@Range[dd, dd + kk*delX, delX] == kk + 1`

Comment: @Jacob The point of `Order` was only to show that there is a difference.  I think there is no bug here, just another complication of floating point arithmetic.